# How to include user in model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to have a user in my model. By user I mean something that holds username. Email and the rest of the stuff would also be nice.

I tried like that:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public virtual MembershipUser Finder { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MyModel mymodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //mymodel.FinderId = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
                mymodel.Finder = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
                _repo.Save(mymodel);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(mymodel);
        }
```

And than in a view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Finder.UserName)
```

While in the controller the poperty UserName was set to "admin" in the view it was null.
On the other hand email was set in both controller and view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to provide this in the `HttpGet`.. not `HttpPost`.. (post is once it's been submitted).

Comment: Is the user authorized? Docorate your Create action with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Sorry, I don't understand. What I posted is the action where mymodel is being saved to the database. And it all works fine except for the MembershipUser. This property is incomplete after save. it contains email but not username.

Comment: Watch all 5 of these videos. They will give you a really good understanding of MVC and creating a user login. They opened my eyes to a lot of MVC magic. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXfhPj1rlQ8&list=SPCD7D098B66C806CA

Comment: What do you get for User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? true/false?